# Выравнмвание flex-элементов

Tags: html, css

Подскажите новичку какими правилами расположить блоки так и с такими размерами, как на фото (возможен вариант в процентах).

[image: Варианты компоновки див-блоков]

```
<!DOCTYPE> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />


</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="header">
</div><!-- #header-->
 <div id="middle">
<div class="left-container">LEFT</div>
<div class="center-container">CENTER
<table width="100%" >
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>text text text text text text t</td>
    <td>text</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>text text text text text text tet</td>
    <td>text</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>text text text text text text tex</td>
    <td>text</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>text text text text text text tex</td>
    <td>text</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>text text text text text text t</td>
    <td>text</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>text text text text text text t</td>
    <td>text</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>text text text text text text text </td>
    <td>text</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>text text text text text text </td>
    <td>text</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>text text text text text text text</td>
    <td>text</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>text text text text text text text te</td>
    <td>text</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>text text text text text text text text text</td>
    <td>text</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>text text text text text text text text text</td>
    <td>text</td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</div>
<div class="right-container">RIGHT</div>
 </div><!-- #middle-->

</div><!-- #wrapper -->

</body>
</html>
```

```css
html, body {
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
 font-size: 17px;
 line-height: 1.4em;
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica,Freeset,Futura, sans-serif;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #000;
 font-weight:900;
}
/*выравнивание первой колонки таблицы */
table tr td{
  text-align:center;
  padding-right:5px
}
/*выравнивание второй колонки таблицы */
table tr td+td{
  text-align:left;
}
/*выравнивание третьей колонки таблицы */
table tr td+td+td{
  text-align:center;
}
table tr td{
    border:1px solid #3a3a3a;
 z-index:1
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
  border-style: hidden;
}
#wrapper {
 margin:auto;
    max-width:980px;
 padding:5px 5px 0 5px
}
#middle{
   display:flex;
   
 
}
#header {
 width: 100%;
 
}
.left-container{
    background-color:red;
    width:150px;
 height:300px;
 text-align:center
}
.center-container{
    background-color: blue;
    width:55%;
 margin-left:10px;
    height:300px;
 text-align:center
}
.right-container{
    background-color: yellow;
    width:300px;
 margin-left:10px;
 height:300px;
 text-align:center
}

@media (max-width: 700px) {
#middle{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 height:600px;
} 
#middle.left-container{ order: left-container; }
#middle.center-container { order: right-container;margin:10px 0 0 0; }
#middle.right-container { order:center-container; }
}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />


</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="header">
</div><!-- #header-->
 <div id="middle">
<div class="left-container">LEFT</div>
<div class="center-container">CENTER
<table width="100%" >
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>text text text text text text t</td>
    <td>text</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>text text text text text text tet</td>
    <td>text</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>text text text text text text tex</td>
    <td>text</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>text text text text text text tex</td>
    <td>text</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>text text text text text text t</td>
    <td>text</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>text text text text text text t</td>
    <td>text</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>text text text text text text text </td>
    <td>text</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>text text text text text text </td>
    <td>text</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>text text text text text text text</td>
    <td>text</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>text text text text text text text te</td>
    <td>text</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>text text text text text text text text text</td>
    <td>text</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>12</td>
    <td>text text text text text text text text text</td>
    <td>text</td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</div>
<div class="right-container">RIGHT</div>
 </div><!-- #middle-->

</div><!-- #wrapper -->

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/e37d90qw/

```css
body { margin: 0; }

main { display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; }
div { height: 3em; }
.l { flex: 1 1 150px; background: red; }
.c { flex: 1 1 350px; background: blue; }
.r { flex: 1 1 200px; background: yellow; }

@media (max-width: 700px) {
  .c { order: 1; }
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class=l></div>
  <div class=c></div>
  <div class=r></div>
</main>
```